# Discontinuous derivative of the below function at $x=0$ reasoning

Tags: limits

The function $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x$ $\neq$ $0$ and 0 for $x=0$ is said to be having a discontinuous derivative at $x= 0$ because of the fact that  limit can be anything between $-1$ to $1$ both including .

> But just from the graph plotted in a graph plotter its a bit intuitive to see that it should be continuous meaning if we draw the graph, as we approach zero we have to make many many such curves from passing through $-1$ to $1$, but still isn't it okay as such from this we can say as we meet at $x= 0$ we are in all just moving from ${-1}$ to ${1}$ value as we approaching it, the graph then made is continuous by the fact that its made without removing the pencil at any time? **There is no sudden jump that can make the function discontinuous at $x= 0$ isn't ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$

1. Show that $f$ is differntiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0.$
2. Show that for $x \ne 0$ we have $f'(x)=2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}).$

Now let $x_n:= \frac{1}{n \pi}$. Then $x_n \to 0$, but $f'(x_n)=(-1)^{n+1}.$

This shows that $f'$ is not continuous at$0$.

Comment: Whats wrong with the sketching of the graph point. I  know of this proof